# Can I detect if user supplied email is actually a distribution list?

Tags: dns, email

I would like to know if I can take an email that a user has entered into our system and check if it is a distribution list before sending any email to it. Is there a way to do this? like by sending a request to the mail server or dns?

Example Flow

- My Software: Hey mail server is dist@example.com a distribution list?
- Mail server: yes it is.
- My Software: (Well I will delete this account then.)

**Context:**
I'm in an enterprise context and every once in a while we get a bunch of noise because someone adds a distribution list email address to our system as a user.

When a new user is added to our system, we fire off a welcome email asking them to confirm their account.

The problem is that when the recipient is a distribution list lots of people get this welcome email and aren't expecting it. Because they likely already have an account for our system, they are confused, suspect phishing, all kinds of stuff, it's a headache... Also because this is an account we've had people actually try to log into it and request a password reset, which fires off more emails... sigh.

Comment: "like by sending a request to the mail server or dns?" No, that is not possible. Even if it were possible your check would be worthless: user set the email as normal, pass your verification and then later changes its system to be a distrubtion list. Same way you can not restrict someone doing a forward of a received email. Whatever your core problem is, the solution is not in that direction. Besides you are offtopic here as this is a generic question not related to programming.

Comment: I fail to see how this is not related to programming, I'm trying to write a program that does this. Where should I ask this question? Thanks for your answer though, I clearly need to think of something else.

Comment: At this stage of your question, there is no code, hence nothing related to programming. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and its 4 bullet points, your question fits in neither of them. For now your question is more about how email works and if there a way to know exactly "who" is behind a given email address. You can do that only if you control the MTA attached to each given email. So possible in a private closed setup, but not in general with any email on the Internet.